# Recursive Javascript counter

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to set up a counter such that works with a recursive function `nextQuestion`, but the value of counter `score` gets reset on each loop. How might one set this up correctly? Or is there a better alternative approach?

```
 nextQuestion(0,0);

  // i = question number
  function nextQuestion(i,score) {
    var currentQ = allQuestions[i];
    $("#question").text(currentQ.question);
    $("#score").text("Your score: " + score);

    $("#quiz").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var choiceSelected = $("input[name='choices']:checked", "#quiz").val();
      var answer = currentQ.correctAnswer
      if (choiceSelected === currentQ.choices[answer]) { 
        score++; 
      }
      i++;
      if ( i >= numQuestions ) { 
        endQuiz(); 
      } else {
        nextQuestion(i,score);
      }
    });
```

Comment: A general rule I follow is that if you need an iterator (question number in your case), recursion probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: This seems like a case of post-increment vs pre-increment but if you're doing recursion you should avoid mutation. The tail call should look something like `return nextQuestion(i+1, score+1)`. But it would be simpler to just loop...

Comment: @Meredith to clarify, I'm trying to increment ```score```, conditionally on correct answer. The ```nextQuestion``` counter works fine.

Comment: @elclanrs thanks but this did not work, ```score + 1``` gets reset to 0.